# Deleting variable names containing specific string

Tags: sas

I'm just starting to learn SAS and wanted to see if anyone knew of a way to delete certain variables from a dataset if they contained a certain word. I'm working with a dataset that contains a huge amount of variables (100+) with the word 'Label' in them and am looking to drop these. Unfortunately the word label comes at the end of the variable name, so I can't do a simple drop label:; Obviously I could individually list all the variables to drop, but I just wanted to see if anyone out there knew of a simpler way to accomplish this task. Thanks for reading and for any help you have to offer up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a the vcolumn table and proc sql to create a macro variable a macro variable:

```
proc sql noprint;

    select trim(compress(name))
    into :drop_vars separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = upcase('lib1')
        and
            memname = upcase('table1')
        and
            upcase(name) like '%LABEL%'
    ;
quit;

%put &drop_vars.;

data table2;
    set table1;
    drop  &drop_vars.;
run;
```

the proc sql will create a list of all the variables from table1 in library `'lib1'` containing `label` anywhere in the name and put it into the macro variable called `drop_vars`. (upcase is used to reduce possibility of case causing an issue)

The data step then uses the `drop` statement and the `drop_vars` variable to drop all variables in the list.

Note: Make sure you check the output of the `%put statement` to ensure you do not drop variables you want to keep

Comment: Why use sashelp.vcolumn and not dictionary.columns?  Same information but skipping the intermediate view.  SASHELP.VCOLUMN is primarily there to allow data step access to dictionary.columns.  Also, why use `noprint` but then put to the log the variable list that is just being suppressed by `noprint`?  Seems like leaving `print` on is more user friendly, since you can see more clearly what's being dropped. :)

Comment: I typically use noprint for all my proc sql statements to suppress outputs on large tables that are output, so it is basically just a habit now and personal preference. Vcolumn is just personal preference, if I encounter a bug it's the table I would check to debug so I found that, for me, I preferred just using that in the code, but if you have a better way I'm always willing to learn.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you for your time and help. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is come up with a dataset that contains the variable names, then create a macro variable containing those you want to drop.  There are three (or more) options for the first part:

- dictionary.columns
- sashelp.vcolumn
- proc contents output to a dataset

All three give the same result - a dataset of variable names (and other things), which you can then query.

So for example, using `PROC SQL`'s `SELECT INTO` functionality to create a macro variable:

```
proc sql;
select name into :droplist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS'
 and name like '%eigh%';
quit;
```

(replace eigh with Label for your needs; % is wildcard here)

and then you have a macro variable `&droplist`, which you can then use in a drop statement.

```
data want;
set sashelp.class;
drop &droplist;
run;
```